# NodeJS Fetch Not Waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to force Node to wait for either a success or a failure. I understood fetch to return a promise and I thought I told it how to handle both.

The following code does not honor the ***await*** I asked it to do:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
        ...
        let fetchResult = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: headers

        }).then(success => {
            console.log("Success reached. " + JSON.stringify(success));
            process.exit(2);
        }, other => {
            console.log("Other reached. " + JSON.stringify(other));
            process.exit(3);
        });
        console.log('@@ after fetch fetchResult=' + fetchResult);
        ...
}
```

You might think that the await would cause it to, wait for the Promise to complete, but instead it leaves the whole function, and goes back to the caller. It does *not* print the '@@ after fetch fetchResult=' line. Neither the failure, nor success handler is executed.

I should point out that it also does not appear to make the requested POST call either. Instead, it sees that request and does something completely different without raising any exception.

Why is it not honoring the 'await' keyword whatsoever?

--- If I try the try/catch approach as follows:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
    console.log('@@getAccessToken BP1');
    if (argumentParserResult.authenticationScheme == 'OAUTH2') {
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP2');
        const fetch = require('node-fetch');
        const url = argumentParserResult.resourceUrl;
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP3');
        let formData = new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': argumentParserResult.clientId,
            'scope': argumentParserResult.clientScope,
            'client_secret': argumentParserResult.clientSecret
        })
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP4');

        let headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP5');


        console.log('POST ' + argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP6');
        try {
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP7');
            const response = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                headers,
            });
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP8');
            console.log(`Success reached.`, JSON.stringify(response));
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP9');
            console.log(`Other reached.`, json);
            return json;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP10');
            console.log(`!! something went wrong`, error.message);
            console.error(error);
            return error;
        } finally {
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP11');
            console.log(`fetch finished`);
        }
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP12');

    }
    console.log('@@getAccessToken BP13');
    return "Should not have reached this point";

}
```

I get

```
@@getAccessToken BP1
@@getAccessToken BP2
@@getAccessToken BP3
@@getAccessToken BP4
@@getAccessToken BP5
POST https://some-url
{}
@@getAccessToken BP6
@@getAccessToken BP7
```

As you can see, it goes just inside of the try block, then goes back to the caller without triggering the finally, error handlers or the logging after the fetch.

Using the .then approach as follows:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
    console.log('@@getAccessToken BP1');
    if (argumentParserResult.authenticationScheme == 'OAUTH2') {
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP2');
        const fetch = require('node-fetch');
        const url = argumentParserResult.resourceUrl;
        console.log('@@BP1.9');
        let formData = new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': argumentParserResult.clientId,
            'scope': argumentParserResult.clientScope,
            'client_secret': argumentParserResult.clientSecret
        })
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP3');

        let headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP4');


        console.log('POST ' + argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
        let response = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: headers

        }).then(success => {
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP5');
            console.log("Success reached. " + JSON.stringify(success));
            return success // !--> LOOK HERE, you should return the success variable
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log('@@getAccessToken BP6');
            console.log(e) // !--> LOOK HERE, if you catch the error, no error will be thrown to the caller
            return e
        });
        console.log('@@getAccessToken BP7');
        console.log('@@ after fetch fetchResult=', fetchResult); // !--> LOOK HERE, this log will always log something now, it could be the responso or the error       

    }
    console.log('@@getAccessToken BP8');
}
```

I get these logs:

```
@@getAccessToken BP1
@@getAccessToken BP2
@@BP1.9
@@getAccessToken BP3
@@getAccessToken BP4
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/5a9bb941-ba53-48d3-b086-2927fea7bf01/oauth2/v2.0/token
{}
```

As you can see above, it goes just to the point of the fetch, then returns to the calling function.

In neither case, can I see any evidence that the fetch was ever called.

Comment: you're using `await` *and* `then`, so the await waits for the promise returned from the then, and you're not returning anything.

Comment: @pilchard That's a fair point. I got the idea from https://igbiriki.medium.com/javascript-fetch-synchronous-or-asynchronous-fd24f8ba6129 which had something of a double Promise, mostly because converting the response to JSON was also asynchronous.

Comment: But why are you exiting the process with non-success codes?

Comment: @pilchard I removed the await, and it at least went to the line after fetch. However, it *still* did not honor the Promise handler, so neither the success nor the failure was returned.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your `then` so I'm not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: @pilchard The process.exit() is there for debugging purposes. I want the fetch result, then have it stop. Sometimes Visual Code's debugger starts then stops and refuses to work, so I have to use a console.log and process.exit()s when it becomes insolent.

Comment: well just `return success` instead of ending the process.

Comment: @pilchard I just want it to call the fetch. Then, since the makers of the language love it so much, call the beloved success handler, or the error handler. But in all cases, ***wait*** for a completion. Right now, it says, oh, I don't have it yet, so let me go to the next line. Or if I was told to await, let me completely ignore that and leave the function and go to the function caller.

Comment: @Woodsman Whether you like or hate Node.JS, but it always just does what you’ve told it to do. It doesn’t have free will. So, it’s very unlikely that it deliberately protests against your direct instructions. It’s far more likely that you are just making a mistake. So, when you find and fix the mistake, Node.JS will become a loyal servant and start working exactly the way you want it to work.

Comment: OK I see your edits and I can not reproduce the behaviour using the `try/catch` solution. But how do you know the function so returning something (I imagine `undefined`) to the caller? Can you show how you are calling the function, in wich context? Also, are you sure there is anything strange within your firewall or connection? because it just looks that the fetch is waiting for a response. And also, wich version of `node-fetch` module are you using?

Comment: Node fetch version 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
async function getAccessToken() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers,
    });
    console.log(`Success reached.`, JSON.stringify(response));
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(`Other reached.`, json);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`!! something went wrong`, error.message);
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    console.log(`fetch finished`);
  }
}
```

You don't need to use thenable object when writing with async/await, instead, catch the error with a try catch bloc, and just get the async value using return of `await`ed function.

Comment: I upvoted the snippet because I find it good at least for learning, but for me, it's refusing to make the call still. Instead, it goes back to the caller. I see no log messages after the fetch, nor any messages in the error handlers. It should take about 0.5 to 1.5s, but instead it comes back right way. Again, with no further information.

Comment: Could you share a reproduction ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `await` and `then`. It is not forbidden, but in most simple case you don't need it.

### Solution without `then`:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        console.log('fetching data') // this log will always appear as first log, before fetching data
        let fetchResult = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, 
            {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
              headers: headers
            })
        let jsonR = await fetchResult.json()
        console.log('fetch done') // this log will appear only if fetch is done with no errors
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('something went wrong', e) // this log will appear only if there was an error
    }
    console.log('after all') // this log will appear always, after fetch (even if fetch fails or not)       
}
```

### Solution with `then`:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
        let fetchResult = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: headers

        }).then(success => {
            console.log("Success reached. " + JSON.stringify(success));
            return success // !--> LOOK HERE, you should return the success variable
        }).catch(e => {
           console.log(e) // !--> LOOK HERE, if you catch the error, no error will be thrown to the caller
           return e
        });
        console.log('@@ after fetch fetchResult=', fetchResult); // !--> LOOK HERE, this log will always log something now, it could be the responso or the error
}
```

As you can see, error handling is not quite convenient in the second solution. That's why you should not mix `await` with `then`, unless you know what you are doing

Comment: For me, the first solution is closer to the native Java I'm more comfortable with seeing. However, it suffers from the same problem as the one above--when the all the Promise headaches are ironed out, it ***refuses*** to even try to fetch. Instead, it just leaves the function. I wish there was a way to tell Node, hey fetch this web site. No really, just fetch it. Don't go off to the back of the postoffice, just do what I asked you to do. Instead, it either returns a promise (that it never fulfills), or completely leaves. FWIW, I can connect fine to the site via a REST tool.

Comment: radar155 and @pilchard: Despite how much I hate Node/Javascript, I really appreciate your help in helping me solve this. I know this is painfully easy if you use it every day.

Comment: Shouldn't the first await ***force*** it to wait for either a success or failure, both of which have a handler, and therefore the last console.log('@@@ after fetch fetchResult=...') would never return? What am I missing with that reasoning?

Comment: I have to admit I can't get your point. Please to understand each other better, consider the first solution I provided ( I edited it with more logs). What's wrong with it? What do you expect with logs I added?

Comment: Both solutions are appreciated, but it's not making the call. That is, it should take about 0.5 to 1.5s to do the POST. The 1st solution enters the try/catch block, and leaves. I added a console.log just inside the try, but before the fetch which does log. None of the logs after the fetch appear, either after the fetch or in the catch. In the second solution, it immediately returns to the caller, but never actually waits for the fetch to occur. Essentially, it never does the fetch. It puts it on a TODO whenever list, and never gets to it.

Comment: So strange, I'm sure you are missing something. Are you sure you added a `console.log` in the `try` block after the `fetch` is made?? Also, how are you calling the `getAccessToken()` function? Maybe you are not using good `promises` or `async/await` in the caller, so data is not where you expect it should be. But even in this scenario, the `fetch` call is 100% made

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I like to think Node isn't just not listening because it somehow knows who I am. I'm working on a way to share the two functions without it breaking stackoverflow's limits.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I added your solutions 1 and 2. I humbly and gratefully ask you to look at them. I believe I've faithfully tried your two approaches and still it fails. I wonder if I have to put my fetch in a while loop forcing it to block.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `async`/`await` is to get rid of the callbacks and make the code more procedural. Your code:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
...
let fetchResult = await fetch(argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: headers
  })
  .then( success => {
            console.log("Success reached. " + JSON.stringify(success));
            process.exit(2);
  }, other => {
            console.log("Other reached. " + JSON.stringify(other));
            process.exit(3);
  });

  console.log('@@ after fetch fetchResult=' + fetchResult);
  ...
}
```

fails, because you are

1. Waiting for `fetch()` to resolve and return a result, and
2. In your `then()` chain, you are
3. Invoking `process.exit()` in the case of either success or failure.

Than means you kill the entire process as soon as the call to `fetch()` resolves with either a success or a failure.

If you do something like this:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
  ...
  const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: headers
  };

  const {json, err} = await execFetch( argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, opts );

  if ( err ) {
    console.log("that didn't work!", err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  ...
}

async function execFetch( url, opts ) {
  const response = { json: undefined, err: undefined };

  const { res, err } = await fetch( argumentParserResult.authorizationUrl, opts )
                       .then(  res => ({ res            , err: undefined }) )
                       .catch( err => ({ res: undefined , err            }) );

  if ( err ) {
    response.err = err;
  }
  else if ( !res.ok ) {
    // non-2xx HTTP status
    response.err = new Error(`${res.status}: ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  else {
    // the 2xx happy path: deserialize the JSON response body into a JS object
    response.json = res.json();
  }

  return response;

}
```

Your call to `fetch()` will **always** succeed and hand you back a *tuple* with a `json` and an `err` property.

A successful call will return something like this:

```json
{
  json: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, },
  err:  undefined,
}
```

Whilst a call to `fetch()` that fails will return something like this:

```
{
  json: undefined ,
  err:  /* some error object with details about what went south */,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but it gets to the execFetch(), calls await fetch(). Neither the .then(), nor the .catch() immediately following the fetch() within execFetch are reached. Instead, it returns to the caller of getAccessToken() as though there was nothing left to do.